# Need to partition month and year from date column in redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a record as '5/30/2016'. Now I want to have month and year from this date column. 
Output I want is as : '5/2016'.
How can I do that in redshift?

Comment: Is `'5/30/2016'` stored as a string (as shown), or is it a date field and `'5/30/2016'` is merely how your SQL tool is displaying it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`select to_char('5/30/2016'::date,'MM/YYYY')`

would give you `'05/2016'`, and if you don't want the first zero you can trim it:

`select ltrim(to_char('5/30/2016'::date,'MM/YYYY'),'0')`

Comment: You can also use the `DATE_TRUNC()` function to round the value back. `SELECT date_trunc('week', '2017-07-13');` = `2017-07-10 00:00:00`